# @exceptionhandler spring mvc 3. Exception needs to handled different in different controllers

Tags: java, exception, spring-mvc, spring-3

Application has internal app support users and external users. Two controllers are used. Both controller queries DB and go through series of workflow steps. When an IO or any other exception occurs , business users needs sorry page. Internal users require the exception time and name of the exception on page.

@ExceptionHandler(IOException.class) is used in both controllers. So same controller advice is invoked. What would be the correct way of implementing this to show different pages with different controllers.

Comment: _is used in both controllers_. Do you mean you have two `@ExceptionHandler` methods, one in each?

Comment: Yes. I have two controllers with one method each. Both those methods are annotated with @ExceptionHandler(IOException.class)

Comment: Write the exception handler method in each controller to do what is needed for that contoller?  It is not clear at all what your problem is the way the question is worded.

Comment: add the Exception to the model and decide on the page who sees what based on their ROLE

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't extends from BaseController in your two controllers and that BaseController has the @ExceptionHandler(IOException.class).

If you want redirect two different pages in the case of exception is raised, consider add a string in an new exception that extends from IOException, catch and rethrow adding the redirect page string